# logging only stderr to a logfile using python logger

Tags: python

I have a logger set up, but I couldn't figure out how to log only if the command fails or generates stderr.

```
def RunAndLog(self, command, logf)
   p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False, 
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   (stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
   logger = logging.getLogger('check rel')
   logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
   filehand = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logFile, mode='a',maxBytes=0,
              backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=0)
   filehand.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
   lformat = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
   filehand.setFormatter(lformat)
   logger.addHandler(filehand)
   logger.info(stdout)
   logger.error(stderr)
   logger.removeHandler(filehand)
```

I am calling this for listing directories. Something like,

```
self.RunAndLog(["dir","%s",pathtodir], "test.log")
```

`test.log` contains messages for both cases, i.e., when the directory doesn't exist and also when it does...  Here is an example :

```
#case where dir doesn't exist
dir: /path/to/dir/dir1: No such file or directory

# case where it does
bin lib include src test python doc
```

How can I log messages to `test.log` only for the cases where the directory doesn't exist or only where the `dir` command fails with non-zero exit status ?

Thanks...

Comment: It is there. Line #3 from the top

Comment: good catch, but that's a typo here when I was pasting... Edited now...

Comment: I suspected as much, because not calling it would result in an exception.

Comment: If this is Python 3: be careful, `subprocess` pipes return `bytes` objects, not `unicode`. Decode them first before logging: `logger.info(stdout.decode('utf8')` (using the correct codec for whatever output the command produces).

Comment: Fantastic... That's the one I was missing for the other question. Thanks. I added `logger.info(stdout.decode('ascii')`. Don't need `literal_eval` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Your `filehandler` handler is catching all log messages. You set its level to ERROR, which makes it catch all messages from ERROR and up (including INFO), that's why every message you log is going into the file.

If you want more control, you'll have to add [Filter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects) objects too.