# python line strip \n and write line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this python code,

```
open('%s.log'%hname,'w').writelines([ line for line in open('%s_tmp.log' %hname) if 'word' in line])
```

This prints the line same as in the `%hname_tmp.log` :

```
b'line contains blah\n'
b'This is the next line\n'
```

I would like to remove `b'` and `\n'` before writing to the new file. Something like this:

```
line contains blah
This is the next line
```

How can I do that ? I have tried

`...writelines([line.rstrip() ...`,

but this jams everything in the new log file in one line while still keeping the `\n'`.

Comment: `re.sub(r'(b\'|\\n\')', '', line) for line in open...`

Comment: You are not telling us the whole story here; it looks as if you opened the input file as binary or are processing the lines such that you end up with `bytes` objects.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ok, the whole story is in another question :). Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471829/logging-only-stderr-to-a-logfile-using-python-logger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the output file as binary:

```
open('%s.log'%hname, 'wb').writelines([ line for line in open('%s_tmp.log' %hname) if 'word' in line])
```

or *decode* the `bytes` objects before writing:

```
open('%s.log'%hname, 'w').writelines([line.decode('ascii') for line in open('%s_tmp.log' %hname) if 'word' in line])
```

If your *original* log file contains those characters, you wrote binary data to *that* log file instead. You can re-interpret those lines as bytes objects by using the [`ast.literal_eval()` utility function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('%s.log'%hname, 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(literal_eval(line.rstrip()) for line in open('%s_tmp.log' %hname) if 'word' in line)
```

`literal_eval()` takes strings that represent Python literals and turns them back into Python objects just like the Python compiler would.

Comment: with `wb` option, it complains, `TypeError: can't write str to binary stream`

Comment: @iamauser: What does `repr(line)` write to the file?

Comment: @iamauser: captured with `subprocess` or similiar? Then you get `bytes` binary data, not Unicode, and you'd have to write that as binary to a file.

Comment: yes, from `subprocess` and using `logger` from python, I write to `.log` file. Sorry, but the `literal_eval()` isn't working for me.`File "/path/sw/python/3.0/lib/python3.0/ast.py", line 67, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed string')`

Comment: `literal_eval()` works. I wasn't using the correct python version when I executed that.... THanks...

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the file as binary.  Try opening with `'rt'`.

```
open('%s.log'%hname,'wt').writelines([ line for line in open('%s_tmp.log' %hname, 'rt') if 'word' in line])
```

Comment: Essentially, both my answer and Martijn's focus on the same thing: text vs. binary files.  Which approach to use depends on whether the source and the target files are (or, meant to be) text or binary.  Based on the `.log` suffix, I assumed they were both text files.

Comment: yes they are. `wt` and `wb' from @Martijn answer don't work. `wt` and `rt` ends up in one line, same as before. May be I should try with `.txt` suffix.

Comment: @iamauser, well, it works OK for me (on a Linux PC).
If it's not working for you, maybe there's something you're not telling us.